# If only supporting iOS6 and above, can eliminate iPhone non retina images?

Tags: ios

I'm wondering, if I only support iOS6 and above on my app, is it safe for me to remove all non retina images art images that are geared specifically for the iPhone? I know that I still have to support non retina for the iPad because iPad2 and iPad Mini (non retina) can still run the latest OS, but is there any flaw in my thinking that I don't have to support iPhone or iPod non retina anymore?

Comment: iPhone 3GS can run IOS6 without having a retina display.

Comment: Also iPad 2 and iPad mini. If it's an iPhone-only app, those devices can still run it and will try to use non-retina assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `imageNamed:` and UIKit in general will use the retina artwork if no non-retina artwork is provided, it's always safe to omit the non-retina artwork.

To more specifically answer the question from your comments, at present there are no non-retina iPhone or iPhone devices that can run iOS 6 or iOS 7 so it is currently safe to assume those devices are all retina.  It is possible that in the future Apple will release a new device with that form-factor that isn't non-retina (imagine a reduced cost iPhone or iPod) though, so it's not a permanently safe assumption.

Bottom line, you don't need to include any non-retina artwork as long as you properly name and reference your retina artwork.

Comment: But I guess what I'm asking is if there isn't any chance of a non retina iPhone device accessing my app since I'm not supporting below iOS6? Because if one does, and I don't have a non retina image for it, could be bad??

Comment: What I'm saying is that it's basically irrelevant whether any non-retina devices can run your app, since the OS is smart enough to make non-retina images from retina images as needed (assuming you use image names that do NOT include the @2x, and the file name always DOES include @2x).

Comment: Yup I definitely do name properly and don't use @2x in the code. Thanks for the response, trying to trim some off my binary.

Comment: How about iOS6 on the 3GS? If it resizes down, it should work, but it's definitely not a retina iPhone.

Comment: It's smart enough to automatically downsize retina artwork and use that, that was pretty much the point of my whole answer.  I haven't included much non-retina artwork in a project in several years.  I do include specific pieces, mostly icons, just because they need to be customized for best appearance.

Comment: @David - from which the only real issue with that is drag on memory? Appearance will be the same?

Comment: "Same" within bounds.  For most purposes, the scaled images are fine and are pretty much indistinguishable from what you would see if you scaled the image in Photoshop.  The exception to that seems to be small pieces with detail, like Icons.